# SSRS not display external image

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, report-designer

In report designer, I have a logo.jpg located in the same directory of the reports. If I set the image source as `external` and path as `logo.jpg`. The image will show in designer preview. However, after I deploy the reports and the image to SSRS server, the image will not show. What happens is the image will be saved in SSRS as resources, but once I click on it it will give me some messy code.

[image: image in ssrs]
[image: when I click open the image]
If I open the report in the application, the image will also not display.

However, if I download it I can view it from my hard drive.

My current fix is to use absolute path in report designer or point to a image in the web, but that is not ideal.

I think that would be a access permission problem but I could not figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried adding the image as part of `Report Data - Images`. Then refer the image in the report by having the `Embedded' option selected.

Comment: @Abhishek No, because I have seen people using external image and have it shown in designer,SSRS and app. I just want to do the same thing.

Comment: Why isn't it ideal to use the absolute path?  That would seem like the standard way to do it.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I think you are right. Maybe I just want to know why using relative path does not work in  my SSRS.. Because I did see it work elsewhere

Comment: I think it would depend on whether the account running the SSRS engine/service has the same relative path set up.  Generally those accounts are not used by a user and so do not have the lettered drives set up.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://convert.town/image-dpi to convert my image to 96 dpi.  SSRS then renders the image correctly in the pdf export.